# Why does rails not respect the type of a belongs_to associated object with STI, when its superclass is abstract?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, abstract-class, belongs-to, sti

I've come across this rather odd bit of behaviour in a rails application I'm working on.

I have multiple types of Post in an inheritance heirarchy, and a Post has_many FeedEntries.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :feed_entries
end

class Post::BlogPost < Post; end
class Post::Discussion < Post; end
class Post::Article < Post; end

class FeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

Now, when I have everything set up as before, calling FeedEntry#post on a saved object always returns an object of the correct (subclass) type, as I would expect. However, if I make Post abstract (which it really should be - the superclass should never be instantiated in this model):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :feed_entries
    self.abstract_class = true
end
```

_(note: I edited this code snippet to take into account tomafro's suggestion below, as setting self.abstract_class seems more idiomatic than overriding self.abstract_class?. However, the same behaviour still persists.)

...then calling the FeedEntry#post association on a previously saved object returns an object of type Post. This seems rather backwards (given that the abstract class declaration denotes specifically that that class should not be instantiated), and I can't think of a reason for this behaviour.

So, is there some reason for this I'm not getting, or is it a bug, or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By specifying `self.abstract_class = true` in the base object, you are essentially disabling STI.  Setting  `self.abstract_class = true` actually tells ActiveRecord that there is **not** a database table associated with that class so your inherited classes will each have their own database table.

It sounds like what you want to do is remove `self.abstract_class = true` and simulate an abstract class by using the initialize method to only permit instantiation if the class is **not** of type `Post`.

For example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
  def initialize 
    raise "Post cannot be instantiated directly" if self.class == Post   
  end
end
```

This way, you maintain your STI model and also have a pseudo-abstract base class.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Aha! That's the one - I'd assumed that activerecord's 'abstract class' property was roughly equivalent to the java-ish definition of it (ie - a class that can't be directly instantiated), when in fact it clearly means something different. Thanks a lot, that clears it up nicely!

Comment: If you found this helpful, would you mind accepting as an answer?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

By overriding the `abstract_class?` method in the superclass, `abstract_class?` will return true for all subclasses, not just the superclass.

Instead I think you should use:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

I've not tried it, but I believe this will fix your issue.

Comment: Aah - sadly not. The behavior is the same with self.abstract_class = true. I think that that's more idiomatic so I'll update the code in my question to reflect it.