# Polymorphic association with abstract class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, polymorphic-associations

So this is more or less of what I'm trying:

I have an abstract class extracted out for all the common functionalities, Which includes a polymorphic association, so it looks like this:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  belongs_to :cardable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end

class Spell < Card
  ...
end

class Unit < Card
  ...
end
```

Now when i try to use polymorphic associations on this, something on the lines of:

```
  class Deck < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cards, :as => :cardable
  end

  class Hand < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cards, :as => :cardable
  end
```

The `belongs_to` part of things work fine,
i.e. `spell.cardable` works perfectly as expected

However, because of the abstract class, `has_many` doesn't work well
i.e. `hand.cards` or `deck.cards` always gives an empty ActiveRecord Association

Is this a workable model, or if not, what would be a better way to model this entire scenario?

Comment: Why do you think you should be using abstract class here in the first place? Without more info it's hard to know WHY or what you're trying to do here so can't provide an answer. It's not best practice with models in rails.  See this article https://medium.com/@jeremy_96642/deep-rails-how-to-use-abstract-classes-6aee9b686e75

Comment: I'm not aware of the concept of an "abstract class" in Ruby. Could you please define the term?

Comment: @lacostenycoder It is because both the child classes have very similar behaviour; however their differences in schema forces me to not use STI

Comment: @CarySwoveland Abstract classes is a concept in rails, where: if you mark a class as abstract, then it does not need a corresponding table (in newer rails versions the autogenerated `ApplicationRecord` class is an example of the same).
and then you can use it as a parent class for inheritance, where each child class will need a different table.

Comment: Josh, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JoshKurien well it sounds like you've answered your own question "it does not need a corresponding table" but in your case aren't `cards` an actual table in your DB? If so, just get rid of this line as it's clearly breaking the polymorphism provided by `ActiveRecord`

```
self.abstract_class = true
```

Perhaps a better way is to just let each model class which has a database table be defined as a regular model. If you need shared behavior in your models, can you use model concerns and extend those models from a shared concern?

See [How to use concerns in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541823/how-to-use-concerns-in-rails-4)

But there are some who think concerns are a bad design, in that case you may also want to check out https://github.com/AndyObtiva/super_module as another alternative.

Comment: nope, cards is not a table for me.
In this case, there are 4 different tables: `spells`, `units`, `decks` and `hands`
The abstract class use case is quite real.

I know that this is breaking polymorphism.
I guess my question was more on what would be a better way to model this scenario

Comment: @JoshKurien I've updated my answer with some other ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate an abstract class by use initializer

```rb
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize 
    raise "Card cannot be instantiated directly" if self.class == Card
  end
  belongs_to :cardable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end
```

you maintain your STI and have pseudo-abstract class
please read this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529916/why-does-rails-not-respect-the-type-of-a-belongs-to-associated-object-with-sti) on stackoverflow:

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I don't have STI in this scenario at all :)

Comment: but yes, would have worked perfectly if it was an STI